# How can I fix this text box print preview?

Tags: c#

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/printingw2form09162005061136am/printingw2form.aspx

```
       for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            // Check if its a TextBox type by comparing to the type of one of the textboxes
            if (Controls[i].GetType() == this.Wages.GetType())
            {
                // Unbox the Textbox
                TextBox theText = (TextBox)Controls[i];
                // Draw the textbox string at the position of the textbox on the form, scaled to the print page
                g.DrawString(theText.Text, theText.Font, Brushes.Black, theText.Bounds.Left * scalex, theText.Bounds.Top * scaley, new StringFormat());
            }
            if (Controls[i].GetType() == this.RetirementPlanCheck.GetType())
            {
                // Unbox the Checkbox
                CheckBox theCheck = (CheckBox)Controls[i];
                // Draw the checkbox rectangle on the form scaled to the print page
                Rectangle aRect = theCheck.Bounds;
                g.DrawRectangle(aPen, aRect.Left * scalex, aRect.Top * scaley, aRect.Width * scalex, aRect.Height * scaley);
                // If the checkbox is checked, Draw the x inside the checkbox on the form scaled to the print page
                if (theCheck.Checked)
                {
                    g.DrawString("x", theCheck.Font, Brushes.Black, theCheck.Left * scalex + 1, theCheck.Top * scaley + 1, new StringFormat());
                }
            }
```

}

I used this code for my print preview but it has an error given for

```
if (Controls[i].GetType() == this.RetirementPlanCheck.GetType())//RetirementPlanCheck
```

and

```
 if (Controls[i].GetType() == this.Wages.GetType())// wages
```

The errors say missing references, so what type of references are those? Please help me to fix this problem.

ERROR MSG
1.'WindowsFormsApplication1.Sinhala' does not contain a definition for 'Wages' and no extension method 'Wages' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Sinhala' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\yashpppp_modi\WindowsFormsApplication1\Sinhala.cs    825 51  WindowsFormsApplication1

2.'WindowsFormsApplication1.Sinhala' does not contain a definition for 'RetirementPlanCheck' and no extension method 'RetirementPlanCheck' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Sinhala' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\yashpppp_modi\WindowsFormsApplication1\Sinhala.cs    WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Put the small section of code that causes the error in your question, and paste the *exact* error message.

Comment: I updated the code can you please help me fixed  this........

Comment: That's good, but can you copy+paste the whole error message too?

Comment: no, I typed it but no key word for RetirementPlanCheck.GetType() ao what can i do

Comment: Please copy and paste the **exact** error message.

Comment: I updated my error msg. please help me

Comment: Does this happen in Visual Studio or when you run the exe after it's deployed?

Answer (score 1):

In the example from C# Corner, the code snippet that you have quoted is in a method of the class `Form1`. This class `Form1` does have two attributes called `Wages` and `RetirementPlanCheck`, defined as

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Wages;
public System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox RetirementPlanCheck;
```

The class in which you are trying to use this does not have these attributes and that is what the compiler complains about.

Did you actually try downloading the full example from the link you provided? It built and ran without any issues for me. Or if you did run into this issue with the provided example, did you maybe delete the `Wages` textbox and `RetirementPlanCheck` checkbox controls by accident from your form?

Comment: So was your issue resolved? How? If so, check out the [FAQ here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for an explanation about accepting the answer.

Comment: thanx it resolved. but I added text and click print preview button it will give exception can you help me fixed it the exception was, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: /*/ Create the source rectangle from the BackgroundImage Bitmap */Dimensions RectangleF srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.BackgroundImage.Width, BackgroundImage.Height);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have any controls called `Wages` or `RetirementPlanCheck`.

I'm guessing those are actually called something else, maybe `txtWages` and `chkRetirementPlan`..

Looking at your code, I think you can probably change your if-statements to avoid this anyway:

```
//if (Controls[i].GetType() == this.Wages.GetType())
if (Controls[i] is TextBox)
...
//if (Controls[i].GetType() == this.RetirementPlanCheck.GetType())
if (Controls[i] is CheckBox)
```

Comment: now it's working but it doesnt show any text if I added text it will terminated. it gives this error msg // Create the source rectangle from the BackgroundImage Bitmap Dimensions
            RectangleF srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.BackgroundImage.Width, BackgroundImage.Height);error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It sounds like you have a new problem. I think maybe you should ask a new question. Remember to post the exact code and **exact** error message! And, don't post code in comments, it's really hard to read. You can post a new question, or edit your original question.

Comment: it was exception, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user1531718 Are you building and running this from the `W2FormMG.zip` example code attached to the C# Corner article, or are you pasting code into your own project?

Comment: no I not downloaded that code I havent any pass word for that site. In my project have sinhala characters so, I want to print preview it. but I used normal print preview. it will not show my text as it is. so, I want used as image so I used this code